# Transposing the product (Vector^T * Matrix^T * Vector)

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, transpose

While studying the basics neccessary for deep learning, I read that for any matrix $\textbf{W}$ and vectors $\textbf{w},\textbf{x}$ with appropriate dimensions so the multiplications are defined, it holds that:

 $\textbf{w}^T \textbf{W}^T \textbf{x} = \textbf{x}^T \textbf{W} \textbf{w}$

However I am not sure how to arrive at this. I know about the general rule for transposing matrix products which states that the transpose of a product is the product of the transposes in reverse order:

$(\textbf{A}\textbf{B})^T=\textbf{B}^T\textbf{A}^T$

So would the derivation be that $\textbf{w}^T \textbf{W}^T \textbf{x} = (\textbf{x}^T \textbf{W} \textbf{w})^T$ and since the result of $\textbf{x}^T \textbf{W} \textbf{w}$ is a scalar we can say $(\textbf{x}^T \textbf{W} \textbf{w})^T = \textbf{x}^T \textbf{W} \textbf{w}$ since the transpose of a scalar is the scalar itself?

I am no Mathematician so this question might seem trivial for many of you, however any feedback is highly appreciated.

Comment: You got it right my friend.  Cheers!

Comment: Thank you Robert :)

Comment: You are more than welcome my friend!

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can do the simple calculation:
Let **w** a matrix Nx1;
Let **W** a matrix MxN;
Let **x** a matrix 1xM;

After calculate the product, you'll see the result is a scalar "1x1", and so you're right.